# Attack/Follow my player

Tags: c#, trigonometry

I want to create a game where you try to avoid objects(circles) that are "attacking" you. The way I did this:

- First calculate the x_and y difference between the object and me (in this code AI_x is the object's x-location (AI_y: y-location) and x, y the player's location)
- Calculate the angle the object has to make in order to go straight towards the player (with Math.Atan(difference between x-axis' / difference between y-axis'))
  -I then use these angles to calculate the x and y distance it has to move per tick (For Example distancePerTick_x = Math.Cos(angle) * speed)

However it doesn't work when my distanceToPlayer_x (see code) is positive or both distanceToPlayer_x and distanceToPlayer_y are negative so the devided number becomes positive again.

I know why this occurs, but I have tried 2 hours to solve it but can't handle the pain anymore :P.

I hope you guys can help me.

CODE:

```
namespace AI
{
    public partial class mainClass : Form
    {
        //variables
        int health;
        double startPosition_x, startPosition_y, angle;
        float x, y, speed, AI_x, AI_y, distanceToPlayer_x, distanceToPlayer_y;

        //gameloop
        Timer gameLoop;

        //field
        Bitmap bmp;

        //player color
        Pen playerColor;

        //Random
        Random random_x, random_y;

    //constructor
    public mainClass()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Initialization();
    }

    //on startup do this:
    private void Initialization()
    {
        //initializing variables
        health = 100;
        speed = (float) 0.75;

        //startposition
        startPosition_x = pbField.Width / 2;
        startPosition_y = pbField.Height / 2;

        //set x and y value to start position
        x = (float) startPosition_x;
        y = (float)startPosition_y;

        //random
        random_x = new Random();
        random_y = new Random();

        AI_x = 0;//random_x.Next(1, 550);
        AI_y = 0;//random_y.Next(1, 320);
        //player color
        playerColor = new Pen(Color.Red, 5);

        //gameloop
        gameLoop = new Timer();
        gameLoop.Tick += new EventHandler(gameMethode);
        gameLoop.Interval = 5;
        gameLoop.Start();
    }

    //the gameloop
    private void gameMethode(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //field
        bmp = new Bitmap(550, 320);
        pbField.Image = bmp;

        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
        {
            //key manager
            if (InputManager.pressed(Keys.W))
            {
                y -= speed;
            }
            else if (InputManager.pressed(Keys.S))
            {
                y += speed;
            }
            else if (InputManager.pressed(Keys.A))
            {
                x -= speed;
            }
            else if (InputManager.pressed(Keys.D))
            {
                x += speed;
            }

            g.DrawEllipse(playerColor, AI_x, AI_y, 5, 5);
            g.DrawEllipse(playerColor, x, y, 5, 5);

            attackPlayer();
        }
    }

    //attack player method
    private void attackPlayer()
    {
        //the distance to the player
        distanceToPlayer_x = AI_x - x;
        distanceToPlayer_y = AI_y - y;

        angle = Math.Atan(distanceToPlayer_y / distanceToPlayer_x);

        Console.WriteLine("Radiants: " + angle);
        Console.WriteLine("Degrees: "+ angle * (180 / Math.PI));

        AI_x += (float) Math.Cos(angle) * (speed/(float)1.25);
        AI_y += (float) Math.Sin(angle) * (speed/(float)1.25);
    }

    //if keydown
    private void mainClass_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        //if escape button is pressed
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

        InputManager.changeState(e.KeyCode, true);
    }

    //if keyup
    private void mainClass_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        InputManager.changeState(e.KeyCode, false);
    }

    }
}
```

Comment: `angle = Math.Atan2(distanceToPlayer_y, distanceToPlayer_x);`, please notice `Atan2`

Comment: What do you mean with Math.Atan2?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.atan2(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Can you write it as an anwser? Because it worked for me, thanks!

Comment: Of course, the next step is to use the Law of Sines to "lead" yourself to the target instead of chasing behind them.  This may make your game too difficult though so beware.

Comment: Hahaha, well the game is about surviving as long as possible and with that feature it will be impossible to survive. But I sure will try it one day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When computing the *entire range* `[0..2 * pi]` angle, a typical solution involves `Atan2` method:

```
 angle = Math.Atan2(distanceToPlayer_y, distanceToPlayer_x);
```

see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.atan2(v=vs.110).aspx
for details